# is it possible to make text in the UILabel different colour?

Tags: ios, uikit, uilabel

Is it possible to make some text in the same **UILabel** in different **colour** and **different size**?

I want it different colour in the same label, is it possible? I mean in one label have many colour of text,

Comment: Maybe you want to add what environment / language / toolkit / system you are talking about?

Answer (score 1):

iPhone doesn't have NSAttributedString, and it's pretty obvious that UILabel doesn't have a way to specify per-character attributes. So I think your only answer is to use WebKit (UIWebView).

Answer (score 0):

You change the text color like this:

```
myLabel.textColor=[UIColor blueColor];
```

You change font like:

```
myLabel.font= aFont; //a font object you've previously defined.
```

See [UILabel Class Reference.](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006797-CH3-SW13)

Edit01: Upon rereading, it appears the OP wants to change text attributes within the same string. In that case, you will need to use [CFAttributedString](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFAttributedString/Reference/reference.html). I haven't used it but I believe it works on the iPhone.

Comment: so usefull answer actually :) thank you so much.
but if i want it diferent colour in the same label if it possible ?
I mean in one label have many clour of text, something like that :/

Comment: I believe that CFAttributedString will give you what you want. It lets you set text attributes like font and color on a character by character basis. It appears from the documentation that it does work on the iPhone whereas NSAttributedString does not.

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS6, you can use the [attributedText](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uilabel/1620542-attributedtext) property of the UILabel to achieve multi colours.